# Obtener los datos de un ítem en el Widget Treeview de tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Quiero preguntar cual función de Treeview puedo usar para que cuando se de click sobre un ítem de la tabla (por ejemplo sobre el número 2, devuelva la fila y la columna) mostrada pueda obtener en una variable o en un arreglo la información del ítem seleccionado asociada a la columna y a la fila en la que se encuentra el ítem seleccionado.

O si es posible poder saber cual el el padre y poder visualizar mediante un arreglo cuales items están bajo el ítem Padre.

Lo anterior será usado para realizar una modificación mediante sentencia SQL a la base de datos.
[image: Tabla de la cual quiero obtener el nombre de la columna y la fila]

Comment: Te recomiendo la siguiente documentación para conocer todos los métodos del treeview: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html En particular yo me fijaría en `.get_children` y `.item`. Además de `.selection` (devuelve una tupla con los ids de los items seleccionados) que no está documentada por alguna razón en la pagina que te pasé.

Comment: Por cierto, si quieres llamar a una función cada vez que un item es seleccionado, puedes usar el evento [`<<TreeviewSelect>>`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview-events.html)

Comment: Me olvide de aclararlo. No existe una función que haga lo que pides. Tendrás que crearla vos. No la crearé por ti, pero te di algo de información para darte un empujoncito para que puedas hacerlo por ti mismo.

Comment: @DanteS. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, voy a revisar los enlaces. Tengo una idea de cómo solucionar lo que quiero hacer pero me hace falta definir como extraer los datos del nodo. Pero con la información que me brindas puedo iniciar.